Copying table data across multiple table using Formulas
So, I have/had an Excel spread sheet that I have been using for years and worked perfectly until my system crashed and the sheet was corrupted. After restoring my system the only back up I can find has none of the formulas anymore. Its been so long since I have worked in excel I cant rework them out and need help?
To make this as simple as I can I have 3 tables I will call them table A, B and C,
Table A, This holds all the data I want to transfer depending on Table B's input to table C.
Table B, This table pulls data from table A using v-look up. So when I enter an item number from table A in to the first column of table B it populates the name from table A in to the 3rd column of table B.
Table C, This is a copy of table A with no data in the rows and where I want data to be pasted to depending on the selection in table B.
Here is the code I used for table B....
=VLOOKUP([@[Column '#]],Table_A[[#All],[Column '#]:[Name]],2)
Here is where I get stuck, What I now want to happen is when The name is populated From Table A to the 3rd column of Table B I want it to copy the full corresponding row of Table A to the first row in table C. All the column names are the same between Table A and C. Columns on Table A and C start at column A and end at column KQ.
